# What does "Swift Interface Summary" in Xcode 6 Jump Bars do?

Tags: xcode, swift, menu

I found there're several new items in Xcode 6 Jump Bars related items menu such as "Original Source" and "Swift Interface Summary". I was confused by **"Swift Interface Summary"**, how can we use it? I couldn't make it active, it's always grayed out.
Thanks!

(From the literal meaning, I guess it's relevant to "@IBOutlet", "@IBAction", "@IBDesignable" or "@IBInspectable", but it seems useless.）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was meant to show the code as it would be seen by consumer importing your target. Have never seen it working in Xcode 6.

It was renamed to Generated Interfaces and actually works in Xcode 7

[image: Generated Interfaces]